# Spark Add New Column with List Count

Tags: list, dataframe, apache-spark, count

Let's say I have the following data - **order_id** and **product_names**.

```
data = [["1", ["Organic A", "Apple"],
        ["2", ["Organic B", "Chocolate", "Organic C]]
```

If I want to create a dataframe and add a new column **product_count** so the output looks like the following, how can I do that?

```
Output:
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|order_id | product_count|                          product_names|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 |             2|                 ["Organic A", "Apple"]|
|       2 |             3| ["Organic B", "Chocolate", "Organic C]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `size` function to get the length of the product_names field.

```
df = df.select('order_id', F.size('product_names').alias('product_count'), 'product_names')
df.show(truncate=False)
```